# Formula Field Count of ActivityHistories

Tags: formula-field, activities

I have a custom object with Activities enabled, as such it has the child relationship `ActivityHistories` - I wanted to show a `count()` of the related `Activities` associated w/ each object of a certain type:

`COUNT(WHERE ActivityHistory.Type = 'Call')`

Is this possible in a Formula Field? I don't see any merge fields for it, and I can't create a `Roll-Up Summary` (inactive the field editor UI, so I assume it's not available that way?)

Or do I have to write a custom trigger and update it when the `Task` is inserted?

Comment: I reckon best bet would be 2 roll-up summaries on Tasks and Events (completed/closed) and then a formula field to sum the two roll-up summaries.

Comment: @Bachovski still `ActivityHistories` is not an available merge field for formula's on my custom object?

Comment: ActivityHistories represent either a Task or an Event that is completed. So your roll up summary would be on both task and event objects. In your formula you'll sum both roll up summary fields

Comment: I dont think we can create roll up summaries in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write an Apex Trigger. The trigger should fire and work on multiple events, like

insert - if a closed activity (even or task is inserted)(+count)
update - if open activity is closed (+count) if closed activity is opened(-count)
delete - if closed activity is deleted (-count)
undelete - if a deleted closed activity is restored.

Let me guide you to a link that can help you to write this trigger. This link calculated count for **OpenActivities**, all you have to do is apply your logics and count for **ActivityHistory**.

http://rjpalombo.com/2013/11/counting-open-activities-salesforce/